# Recover Channel from Rabbitmq by used Lyra

Tags: rabbitmq

EveryOne. Lyra will recover the channel again and again when i force the connection close by web monitor.So more and more threads is create by rabbitmq-client, How can i do with it? thx~

Like this:

com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 6, class-id=60, method-id=80)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:484)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:321)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:554)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

when i use:

channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false); in defaultConsumer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error:

> PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 6,

Which means that you are trying to ack a message with a deliver tag that didn't arrive via the channel that's trying to send the ack.